# Is shop by brand a standard feature on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

So layered navigation is a standard feature and it has brands in. What about a page within a category that lets you shop by brand of that category.

I feel like this is very similar to the layered navigation page.

However is there a standard magento way of creating a page within a category that you can shop by brand?

Comment: Stevie, magento does not have  feature shop by brand  feature